# How to make an auto-scrolling textbox in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll

In one of my projects, I would like to have an auto-scrolling textbox.

I'm not talking of a textbox that scrolls whenever someone adds a text line, but of something which is like a movie ["closing credits"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits) sequence.

The textbox would be fullfiled with text and down-scroll slowly without any user action.

Is there any existing widget that would fit this purpose ? If not, what would be the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraphicsView approach is the most flexible one I think, if you want something fancy.

An easier approach might be using the "Animation Framework", setting up a QPropertyAnimation and to connect it to the "value" property of a QTextBrowser's vertical scrollbar. (Have a look at the Animation Framework examples).

Answer (score 1):

Use QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsTextItem. With QGraphicsTextItem you can use html to format your scrolling text nicely. Then start a timer to move the QGraphicsTextItem.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't I scroll the viewport instead of moving the `QGraphicsTextItem` ?

Answer (score 1):

Roku's suggestion to use QGraphicsView is a good one, but in the event that you're looking for complex text rendering, you may not wish to use QGraphicsView.

Another way to do it is to use [QTextDocument](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtextdocument.html)'s rendering capabilities (à la [QAbstractTextDocumentLayout](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html)) in order to draw the text region of interest.  Scrolling is then simply a matter of calling update() to render a new portion of the text region.

Here's some Python (PyQt) that represents the drawing portion of what you need to do:

```
# stored within your widget
doc = QTextDocument(self)
doc.setHtml(yourText) # set your text
doc.setTextWidth(self.width()) # as wide as your current widget
ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
dl = doc.documentLayout()

# and within your paint event
painter.save()
# you're probably going to draw over the entire widget, but if not
# painter.translate(areaInWhichToDrawRect);
painter.setClipRect(areaInWhichToDrawRect.translated(-areaInWhichToDrawRect.topLeft()))
# by changing the drawing area for each update you emulate scrolling
ctx.clip = theNextAreaToDraw()
dl.draw(painter, ctx)
painter.restore()
```